# unable to get MonoForAndroid_API_14 in Visual Studio 2013 Professional with Xamarin installation

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to build an android application in `C#` using `Visual Studio` with `Xamarin for visual studio`(included). With the basic installation, I tired to create a basic "hello world" program. Successfully built the project, selected `MonoForAndroid_API_10` and tried start Debugging.

It shows pop-up as `your google emulators are slow` --> discarded this pop-up -- I was expecting my output as a blank screen with hello world text at center and nothing more than this. But, the Emulator shows the output as a mobile application (with a lock screen and built-in apps), not the one I was expecting.

I anticipate like if I'm missing to enable `MonoForAndroid_API_14` and later versions.

I couldn't information regarding how to enable MonoForAndroid_API_14. I installed all the packages using the Android SDK tools. But couldn't get the emulators to execute my project.

Comment: `I couldn't get the desired output.` is not a proper problem statement. What is the actual output? do you get any exceptions? does the application crash? does the emulator even start? please be specific. BTW, google emulators are completely unusable. I have had **MUCH** (I can't stress this enough) better results using the GenyMotion emulator. Google is a company that does a damn good job in creating search engines but they really suck at creating software development tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was expecting my output as a blank screen with hello world text at center and nothing more than this. But, the Emulator shows the output as a mobile application (with a lock screen and built-in apps), not the one I was expecting.

When you run the emulator, it starts Android like a normal physical Android device. Your app is then deployed by the Xamarin Runtime and you can access it like any other Android app from your device's main menu. Scroll down the menu and behold your installed app right there.

Comment: No, I couldn't find any app in my device